# If AD group gets a rename will SP automaticly understand its same group just different name?

Tags: 2010, active-directory, ad

If AD group gets another name will SP automaticly understand its same group just different name or do I need to remove it and add it again in site permissions?

Comment: Just run a user profile sync again.

Comment: Notice: since based on my experience such approach sadly seem to be fairly common, please ensure that the group aren't being renamed by deleting and recreating them under a different name...

Comment: Removing the group from the site (via the UI) and re-adding it will retain the old name. You will either need to delete the SPUser object from the site entirely or update the object with the new name using PowerShell.

Comment: @SPArchaeologist Its existing group is being renamed

Answer (score 4):

Either you rename the AD group at AD or Migrate the ad groups from the different domains, names of the AD groups in SharePoint won't change.

Interestingly, they will continue to work as they always have since SharePoint is really using the Security Identifier and not the name of the group.

Now you have to two options

1. Delete and recreate the groups.
2. Run powershell against each site collection level where it is being used.

   ```
   $sites = get-spsite -limit all
   foreach ($site in $sites)    
   {
       $user = get-spuser -identity "c:0+.w|s-1-5-21-2519571660-2376940383-2348130139-2109" -web $site.url -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

       If($user)    
       {    
           set-spuser -identity $user -displayname "PEET\MigratedGroup"    
           Write-host –foregroundcolor green "Changed the name for $($site.url)"

       }    
       Else    
       {    
           Write-host –foregroundcolor red "The specified group does not exist in $($site.url)"    
       }
   }
   ```

[Renaming an AD group in SharePoint 2013](http://www.sharepointfire.com/2013/11/renaming-an-ad-group-in-sharepoint-2013/)

[Windows SharePoint Services does not synchronize a new name change to Active Directory](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/906951)

Comment: If you have configured the UPS, shouldn't it update the group name in SharePoint the next time a sync runs?

Comment: for AD name, looks like not

Comment: I could have sworn it did so I just tested to confirm and you're right. The name doesn't get updated in the sites. The new name appears in the people picker but not the site. You would likely need to Move-SPUser/Set-SPUser as you detailed.

Comment: thats what i think until today...So i tested it and found the same thing.